# Passing multiple parameters to WebAPI

Tags: json, post, asp.net-web-api

I have a simple Post method

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Conversation))]
[HttpPost]
[Route("foo/bar/Function/")]
public Conversation Function(string title, IEnumerable<Participants> participants)
{
}
```

I would like to pass some the title and the participants from my application to the service.

This is what I have tried:

```
var createNewConversation = function(title, participants) {
var deferred = $q.defer();
var data = {
    title: title,
    participants: participants
};

$http.post("/foo/bar/Function", data, { headers: { 'Content-Type': "application/json" }, withCredentials: true }).success(function(response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
    }).error(function(err, status) {
        deferred.reject(err);
    });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

But the request never gets to the service (aka not hitting the breakpoint).

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are sending the two param inside the body, and web api cannot manage this, you have two options:

**1. Send the title in the URL and participans in body:**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Conversation))]
[HttpPost]
[Route("foo/bar/Function/{title}")]
public Conversation Function(string title, IEnumerable<Participants> participants)
{...}
```

//js

```
var data = {
    participants: participants
};
$http.post("/foo/bar/Function/title", data, ......
```

**2. Send all in the body, change the action:**

```
[ResponseType(typeof(Conversation))]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("foo/bar/Function/{title}")]
    public Conversation Function([FromBody] MyClassThatHaveTitleAndParticipants data)
    {...}
```

The class MyClassThatHaveTitleAndParticipants must have the two properties, title and participants.
//js

```
var data = {
    title: title,
    participants: participants
};

$http.post("/foo/bar/Function", data, ...
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot :)